# Using font awsome with antd

Tags: antd

Can someone give an example of how to use get Font Awesome working with AntD framework? They mentioned you can use SVG with external icons.

Thanks,

Thaban

Comment: If you are using react, antd [recommends](https://ant.design/docs/react/recommendation) to use [react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) or [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons).

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can make an IconFont component yourself.

### Steps

1. Create icon files using tools like [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/).
2. Create your IconFont component.
3. Use the component as you like(support string props).

### IconMoon usage

1. Open https://icomoon.io/app/#/projects
2. Create your project.(Notice: it's saved locally for normal user). Click 'load project' on right side.
3. upload your svg files and name them(this name will be used in you react component).
4. select download panel in the bottom of page and download files.
5. then you get a zipped file.

```
|-demo-files  
  |-some demo files.
|-fonts
  |-iconfont.eot
  |-iconfont.svg
  |-iconfont.ttf
  |-iconfont.woff
|-demo.html  
|-style.css
|-something not important
```

### Create IconFont Component

1. add unzipped files under fonts fold to your project's assets. maybe `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/assets/icons/fonts/`
2. create a component

```
// src/components/IconFont/IconFont.jsx
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import './icon.less';

const IconFont = ({ type, active, className, size = 16, style, ...rest }) => (
    <i
        {...rest}
        style={{ fontSize: size, ...style }}
        className={classNames(
            'icon',
            {
                'icon_active': active,
                [`icon-${type}`]: type,
            },
            className
        )}
    />
);

export default IconFont;
```

```
// src/components/IconFont/icon.less
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your-iconfont-name';
    src: url('../../assets/icons/fonts/iconfont.eot');
    src: url('../../assets/icons/fonts/iconfont.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../assets/icons/fonts/iconfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../assets/icons/fonts/iconfont.svg#live') format('svg');
}
.icon {
        font-family: 'your-iconfont-name' !important; // font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        transition: 0.3s;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        vertical-align: middle;
        // things under refer to style.css in unzipped files.
        &.icon-female:before {
            content: "\e901";
        }
        &.icon-male:before {
            content: "\e902";
        }
        &.icon-close:before {
            content: "\e900";
        }
    }
```

### Usage

now you can use the component.

```
// src/components/Foo/Foo.jsx
import IconFont from '../IconFont/IconFont';
...
render(){
  return <IconFont type="male" />
}
...
```

Comment: Thank Narro. How will this work this with AntD framework? I need to able to use with their other components which requires their Icon Component to be the input props to make it work.

Comment: what if implement a proxy component returning AntD Icon or our IconFont according to icon props? `if (type.indexOf("prefix-xxx")){ return <IconFont type={type}/>}else {return <Icon type={type} />}`

Comment: @Narro, thanks for your help. Just a note: you forgot to import the style.css file to IconFont.jsx

Answer (score 1):

Just import the SVG, for example download an icon from font-awesome, and use it within the `component` property of `Icon`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Icon } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { ReactComponent as IconLogo } from './Logo.svg';

const App = () => <Icon component={IconLogo} style={{ fontSize: 200 }} />;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-58901794-IconExample]

Refer to [custom SVG icon in docs](https://ant.design/components/icon/#Custom-SVG-Icon).

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Is there a way to use it via string name (e.g "fas fas-dollar").

Comment: No, only built in icons, you can check the strings available at the docs